# ¿Cómo inhablitar el autocompletado y sugerencias de correcciones en campos HTML?

Tags: html

¿Cómo se hace para anular desde *HTML* la sugerencia sobre los datos ingresados por el usuario? Por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente campo `input` de una aplicación en *Angular*:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="place2search" autocomplete="off" >
```

... y aparecen sugerencias *"llamo"* cuando se ingresa *"llao"*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `autocomplete` en `"off"` está agregado, como se ve en la consola *HTML*. ¿De qué manera se podría inhabilitar desde la aplicación?

Comment: Encontré la solución con spellcheck="false", abajo hay mas detalle, gracias por las sugerencias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autocomplete presenta algunas dificultades, [según dice Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

Ellos sugieren las siguientes formas, se puede probar una por una, ya que según el tipo de navegador que uses y si tu formularios pide datos del tipo password funcionará una u otra:

```
 1. autocomplete="off"
 2. autocomplete="nope"           //una cadena aleatoria cualquiera
 3. autocomplete="new-password"   //formularios que piden password
```

Ahora explico, según Mozilla, por qué las posibilidades 2 y 3.

> In some cases, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values
>   even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected
>   behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really
>   forcing the no-autocompletion is to assign a **random string** to the
>   attribute:
>
> ---
>
> En algunos casos, el explorador seguirá sugiriendo valores de autocompletado incluso si el atributo autocompletar está desactivado. Este comportamiento inesperado puede ser muy desconcertante para los desarrolladores. El truco para forzar a que no use autocompletar es **asignar una cadena aleatoria al atributo**, por ejemplo:

```
 autocomplete="nope"
```

### El atributo autocomplete y los campos de inicio de sesión

> Modern browsers implement integrated password management: when the user enters a username and password for a site, the browser offers to remember it for the user. When the user visits the site again, the browser
>   autofills the login fields with the stored values.
>
> Additionally, the browser enables the user to choose a master password
>   that the browser will use to encrypt stored login details.
>
> Even without a master password, in-browser password management is
>   generally seen as a net gain for security. Since users do not have to
>   remember passwords that the browser stores for them, they are able to
>   choose stronger passwords than they would otherwise.
>
> For this reason, many modern browsers do not support
>   autocomplete="off" for login fields:
>
> If a site sets autocomplete="off" for a form, and the form includes
>   username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer
>   to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will
>   autofill those fields the next time the user visits the page. If a
>   site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password input fields,
>   then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the
>   user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the
>   user visits the page. This is the behavior in Firefox (since version
>   38), Google Chrome (since 34), and Internet Explorer (since version
>   11).
>
> If an author would like to prevent the autofilling of password fields
>   in user management pages where a user can specify a new password for
>   someone other than themself, autocomplete="new-password" should be
>   specified, though support for this has not been implemented in all
>   browsers yet.
>
> ---
>
> Los navegadores modernos implementan la gestión integrada de contraseñas:
>   cuando el usuario introduce un nombre de usuario y una contraseña para
>   un sitio, **el navegador ofrece recordarlo para el usuario**. Cuando el
>   usuario vuelve a visitar el sitio, el navegador rellena
>   automáticamente los campos de inicio de sesión con los valores
>   almacenados.
>
> Además, el navegador permite al usuario elegir una contraseña maestra
>   que el explorador utilizará para cifrar los datos de inicio de sesión
>   almacenados.
>
> Incluso sin una contraseña maestra, la administración de contraseñas
>   en el navegador suele considerarse como una ganancia neta para la
>   seguridad. Dado que los usuarios no tienen que recordar las
>   contraseñas que el navegador almacena para ellos, pueden elegir
>   contraseñas más fuertes de lo que lo harían de otro modo.
>
> **Por esta razón, muchos navegadores modernos no admiten autocomplete =**
>   **"off" para los campos de inicio de sesión**:
>
> Si un sitio establece autocomplete = "off" para un formulario, y el
>   formulario **incluye campos de entrada de nombre de usuario y
>   contraseña,** **el navegador seguirá ofreciendo recordar este inicio de
>   sesión** y si el usuario acepta, el navegador los rellenará
>   automáticamente la próxima vez que el El usuario visita la página. Si
>   un sitio establece autocomplete = "off" para los campos de entrada de
>   nombre de usuario y contraseña, el navegador seguirá ofreciendo
>   recordar este inicio de sesión y, si el usuario lo acepta, el
>   navegador los rellenará automáticamente la próxima vez que el usuario
>   visite la página. Este es el comportamiento en Firefox (desde la
>   versión 38), Google Chrome (desde 34) e Internet Explorer (desde la
>   versión 11).
>
> **Si un autor desea evitar el relleno automático** de los campos de
>   contraseña en las páginas de administración de usuarios donde un
>   usuario puede especificar una nueva contraseña para alguien que no sea
>   uno mismo, **debe especificarse autocomplete = "new-password", aunque el
>   soporte para esto no se ha implementado en Todos los navegadores
>   todavía**.

Lo que dice en esencia es que, en algunos navegadores, en los formularios que tengan campos de password, autocomplete *no hará caso aunque esté en off* y seguirá sugiriendo datos... para apagarlo hay que hacer algo un tanto raro :)

```
   autocomplete="new-password"
```

Prueba esas tres posibilidades.

**EDIT**
En el caso concreto de esta pregunta, al OP le ha funcionado agregar el siguiente atributo al input en cuestión:

```
    <input .... spellcheck="false"> ... </input>
```

Comment: Gracias por la información @A.Cedano. No tenía idea que un string random tuviera ese efecto

Comment: De nada @amenadiel Es algo interesante y "raro". Sospecho que pronto corregirán eso, pues es increíble que haya que resolver ese problema de esta forma. :)

Answer (score 6):

Encontré la solución agregando el atributo **spellcheck="false"**, y quedó así:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="place2search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias por las sugerencias..

Comment: Marca la respuesta como solucionado, de lo contrario quedaría como sin resolver.

Answer (score 3):

Solo necesitas el "autocomplete" con el atributo off, que raro que no te funcione...

Nota funciona en HTML5.

Pero bueno aquí tienes un ejemplo oficial (en inglés) de la w3 espero que te sirva.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: No funciona en últimas versiones de firefox. Y, en la **documentación oficial** de la recomendación [HTML Standar 4.10.18.7.1 - autocomplete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-autocomplete) **dice explícitamente:** "... the "on" and "off" keywords are not allowed" que se parece mucho a que off no esta permitido para el atributo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con el atributo `autocomplete="off"` (creo que solo funciona en *HTML5*).

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="place2search" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Hola, hice la prueba con autocomplete="off", pero sigue apareciendo la palabra con sugerencias. Actualice la pregunta para que se vea que pasa y cual es codigo HTML